# Дублируется запись в сессии из формы PHP

Tags: php, сессия

Есть форма с кнопкой, где методом POST передаются данные сессию.

```
$_SESSION['global_str'][] = $_POST;
```

Все отлично работает, но если обновить страницу, то даже с не заполненной формой,  дублируются предыдущие данные. Получается, если 20 раз обновить страницу, добавится 20 одинаковых массив в сессию.

Помогите сделать проверку, что если такое уже есть в **$_SESSION['global_str']**, тогда не добавлять.

Пробовала array_unique, но все перестает работать.

Comment: после успешного выполнения POST запроса обычно делают редирект на get-запрос, тогда проблема повторной отправки данных исчезает.

Comment: Так вы не пробовали проверять POST на пустоту? Типа, если `empty($_POST)`, то ничего не делаем, точнее если `!empty($_POST)`, то добавляем `$_SESSION['global_str'][] = $_POST;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count_arr = count($_SESSION['global_str']) - 1; // проверить количество записей в массиве и минус 1, потому как счет идет с нуля

// если запись не равна, то добавить строчку
if ($_SESSION['global_str'][$count_arr]['text_tab1'] !== $_POST['text_tab1']) {
    $_SESSION['global_str'][] = $_POST; // запись данных с формы в сессию
}
else {
    echo "запись есть, ничего не делать, просто вывести это сообщение";
    
}
// если запись не равна, то добавить строчку
```

Вероятнее всего у вас массив с индексами, поэтому вычисляется последний элемент и по нему идет проверка. 
**['text_tab1']** - сюда подставьте название одно/несолько название полей из формы.
Не идеально, но вашу задачу решит 100%.